# Лингвистическое наблюдение

Tags: общие-вопросы

За последнюю неделю дважды слышала новое для меня слово "еёшный". Оно меня огорчило, так как не вписывается в мою доморощенную "теорию". Вот она:

Бывают случаи массовых ошибок, которые школа и наука пытаются "вытравить", но безуспешно. Почему же эти речевые нарушения такие живучие?  Я вижу несколько разных причин. 
 1. Например, неправильные ударения могут закрепиться в определенной среде и передаваться от человека к человеку. Потому что в книгах ударений нет. Да и не все читают книги.
 2. Иногда в языке нет средств для выражения определенных смыслов, поэтому "народный" язык затыкает эти дыры. Именно к такому случаю, как мне кажется, относится слово "ихний", -ие, -яя, -ему ... Все многочисленные варианты в литературном языке сводится к слову "их", так что оттенки смысла приходится извлекать из контекста.

Но слова "она" хорошо и разнообразно склоняется, так что "её" не перепутаешь с "ей" или "ею". Зачем же еще наращивать это слово?

Впрочем, раньше я слышала слово "ейный", "еённый" для обозначения принадлежности объекта. Может, слово "её" кажется слишком коротким?

И вообще, поставлю вопрос широко. Лингвистическая наука изучает, как говорить *правильно*. А есть ли такая наука, которая изучает неправильную речь? Почему ошибки существуют? Почему они именно такие? Почему так живучи? Помесь лингвистики с психологией и социологией.

Comment: основная причина "массовых" ошибок - попытка образовать что-то (форму слова, синтакчическую связь и т.д.) по некому общему правилу в то время как случай относится к особым или просто исключениям. 
"Неправильные" притяжательные местоимения - как раз из сила таковых.
В целом вопрос меня не очень вдохновил. Мало ли какие варианты может изобрести язык...

Comment: Вы, наверное, наложили на себя епитимью: отвечать на все вопросы, даже те, которые Вас "не вдохновляют".  Не мучайте себя, пожалуйста!  
Меня, конечно, интересует не столько конкретный монстр типа "еёшный", сколько внимание _науки_ к носителю языка "как он есть", а не к продукту (речи), оторванному от своего создателя (народа).

Comment: Спасибо за разрешение. Я обычно отвечаю, когда мне есть что сказать по теме. В данном случае по теме была только реплика о причинах ошибки. Остальное меня действительно не вдохновило. Ибо "мыслию по древу". Основная, если не единственная, причина массовых ошибок - применение общих моделей там, где в силу вступают частности и исключения.

ЗЫ Вы, боюсь, не совсем верно трактуете "епитимью". Это искупительная мера по исполнению деяний безусловно благих, если они оказываются некстати, то это уже не эпитимья, а что-то другое.

Comment: Ну, Вы то считаете, что Ваш ответ нужен: иначе зачем же страться? ;-)))  
Ладно, закрываем шутку.

Comment: Я ж говорю: "не совсем верно трактуете".)))
У меня было: "... деяний **безусловно** благих".

Comment: >  "... деяний __безусловно__ благих".  
А что, такие существуют? Обычная епитимья состоит, как я понимаю, в чтении "Отченаша". Для меня, как для атеистки, это не является благом.  
А впрочем, закроем постороннее обсуждение.

Comment: Снова прыгаю. Ареал диалекта может быть любой. Конкретные особенности речи могут быть присущи нескольким диалектам или даже целому наречию, но надо проделать немыслимую работу, чтобы все их зафиксировать и привязать к местности. Хорошо, оставим диалектологию. Должны быть другие подразделения лингвистики, изучающие ошибки, отклонения от лит. нормы. Интересно выяснить, какие именно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я думаю, что при употреблении  "ихний" вместо "их", "ейный" "евонный" вместо "её" и "его" происходит разграничение местоимений. Ведь есть "Я" - личное и "МОЙ" - притяжательное, есть "ТЫ" и "ТВОЙ", "МЫ" и "НАШ", "ВЫ" и "ВАШ", а для притяжательного значения местоимений, образованных от 3 лица, таких форм нет: притяжательные местоимения "его", "его", "их" совпадают с формами личных местоимений. Вот и происходит в речи дифференциация.

Лингвистика изучает любую речь. Правда, раньше изучалась прежде всего речь письменная. С развитием техники появилась возможность изучения и устной речи. Ясно, что в устной неподготовленной речи ошибок больше, чем в письменной. А ошибки свидетельствуют именно о том, что язык - живой организм, постоянно изменяющийся и развивающийся.

Comment: Точно! Мои мысли двигались куда-то туда же.  
Получается, что "простой" носитель языка неосознанно делает его более логичным, регулярным и закономерным. Но научную и культурную общественность такая "правильность" не устраивает, так как она противоречит каким-то более глубоким законам и потребностям языка.

Answer (score 0):

Одно из подразделений лингвистики, изучающее внелитературную речь, - диалектология. Употребление "ихний" вместо "их", "ейный" "евонный" вместо "её" и "его" наверняка характерно для диалекта - местного наречия, говора. Строго по-научному, диалект - явление локальное и по масштабу небольшое (Смоленский диалект, Черниговский), а наречие - целая группа диалектов, иногда очень большая.

Comment: Спасибо! Информация интересная! Только, наверное, эти разделы изучают состояние говоров и их отличие от литературного языка. А вот изучает ли кто-нибудь причины живучести тех или иных особенностей? На уровне психологии? А то у нас есть норма и есть массовая речь, а почему они не сходятся друг с другом - непонятно.

Comment: Нет. Это совсем не длиалектные явления. Во-первых, они не локализуемы,  во-вторых у них есть "общелитературная" причина. 
Ну и наконец, диалекты русского - это в основном фонетика. грамматических явлений на диалектном уровне почти не фиксируется. А те, что есть, объясняебтся сохранением "языковой памяти", а не утратой её.

Comment: Начсет "строго по научному". Увы, но четкого разделеняи между понятиями наречие, говор, диалект и т.д. нет и никогда не бцло. Есть некоторый набор признаков-критериев, но он никогда не был универсальным.

Comment: По идее этим должна заниматься психолингвистика. Правда, какие есть наработки по этой теме, мне сложно сказать.

Comment: Из всей психолингвистики мне попадалась только книга Р.Фрумкиной "Цвет. Смысл. Сходство", которую я очень люблю за четкость постановок задач и их решений. Использую в преподавательской деятельности. Наверное, в этой области есть много исследований!

Comment: Насчет "строгости" я, может, и перегнула палку, но что наречие объединяет в себе диалекты - это для меня очевидно, по крайней мере так нас в универе учили. Другие версии есть, но эта является приоритетной.

Comment: Ох и нифигасе... А по какому учебнику вас учили?
Понимаете, сама это иерархическая схема с четырьмя таксонами (язык-наречие-диалект-говор) имеет какой-то сымсл только в языковой систематике, предмете весьма далеком от актуальных нужд простого лингвиста. В других случаях и подход другой, вплоть до того, что диалект - это любой язык и вообще все эти терсины - синонимичны.   
Все бы ничего, не стал бы я о теминах спорить, но я не вижу реальных критериев для разграничения иерархических таксонов. Более того, я не понимаю даже, почему из именно четыре.

Comment: Да, у меня тоже такие остаточные знания по диалектологии, как и у Инны. И еще. Диалектные особенности это не только фонетика! Еще и лексика! Словно другой язык.

Comment: Согласна с @Ларf: это другой язык, а не только фонетика. Так что все эти "еёшные" и "евонные" вполне могут быть характерны для диалекта, несмотря на то, что никто из нас этого точно не знает.

Comment: Меня лично устраивает такая иерархическая схема, и глубже лезть особо желания нет. Учебника по диалектологии не припомню чтоб был, только лекции конспектировали. Да, надо сказать, что я на украинской филологии училась. И едва не единственное, что запомнила по диалектол. - что на терр. Украины три наречия: юго-западное, северо-восточное и северное, в рамках каждого из них свои диалекты. Увы, мои познания правда не глубоки.

Comment: А каков в наше время может быть ареал диалекта? Я слышала "еёшный" 1) по телевизору, мальчик сказал (помнится, городской) и 2) у себя в городе (миллионном). Что же это за диалект, распространенный на тысячи километров?

Answer (score 0):

Если  считать  слово  диалектным,  то  это  не  ошибка  а  другая  норма.

Comment: Смотря что считать ошибкой. Если отклонение от литературной нормы языка (не диалекта), то диалектное слово - ошибка.

Comment: Я бы сказал: смотря что считать нормой.